# Can I use Feyman-Kac here when the derivative is squared?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I find the below problem very strange since the derivative in the SDE is squared. Can I even use Feynman-Kac here because the derivative is squared? An in that case how would that formula look like?

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Feynmac-Kac formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula

It does not matter that the terminal condition be zero, because you have a term $q(t,x)$ (which corresponds to $f(x,t)$ in their article)

Comment: Thank you! But can I even use the Feynman-Kac formula here when the derivative is squared?

Comment: Apply Feynmac-Kac with $v(t,x)=\exp(u(t,x))$.